# удалить элемент и соседние

Tags: python, list, for

дана строка `'s*zz'`
нужно удалить из нее элементы, соседствующие с `'*'` и саму `'*'`, как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `import re re.sub(r".{1}\*.{1}", "", a)`

Comment: Да, пожалуй через регулярки гораздо проще, я пытался на чистом питоне изобразить, но там длинно и некрасиво выходит )

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 

a = "hell*owor*ld"
re.sub(r".{1}\*.{1}", "", a)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уточнять не вижу смысла, ваше подсказка помогла решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без регулярок, но у меня как-то очень заумно получилось. Так что лучше через регулярки, да.

```
s = 'ss*zz*ddfsdf*dffsdf'
sp = s.split('*')
print(''.join(x[(1,0)[not i]:(-1,None)[i==len(sp)-1]] for i,x in enumerate(sp)))
```